# React Native ListView with refresh control doesnot work on Android

Tags: android, react-native

I am new to `react native`. I am trying to test `Listview`  with `refresh control` on Android. The pull to refresh works when the `Listview` contains only one row to render, but it doesn't call refresh function when there are more than 1 row to display. I looked online various examples,but couldn't figure out what is wrong with below code.

```
<ListView     
   refreshControl={
                <RefreshControl
                  refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
                  onRefresh={this._onRefresh.bind(this)}
                  tintColor="#ff0000"
                  title="Loading..."
                  titleColor="#00ff00"
                  colors={['#ff0000', '#00ff00', '#0000ff']}
                  progressBackgroundColor="#ffff00" />
              }
   automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
   dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
   renderRow={this.renderFeed.bind(this)}
   renderHeader = {this.renderHeader.bind(this)}
   renderSeparator={this.renderSeparator}
   onEndReached={this.onEndReached.bind(this)}
   scrollRenderAheadDistance={500}
   onEndReachedThreshold={100}
/>

_onRefresh()
   {

      this.setState({refreshing: true});
      console.log('refreshing....')
      setTimeout(() => {
         this.setState({
            refreshing: false
         });
      }, 3000);
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

Wrap your Listview in a view with contentContainerStyle set to that view

```
<View contentContainerStyle={{flex: 1}}>
    <ListView
     //list view content here

/>
</View>
```

Hope this works

Comment: You can also wrap it in a ScrollView as well.